# total sum of 2d array values c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2015

Hi guys i am trying to create a retrieve method to retrieve a sum total of my 2d array values i have built the array to fill from user input but not sure how to total all array values as i am still learning.

```
public int[,] ToysMade = new int[4, 5];
public String[] days = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };

    public void UserInput()
    {
        String value;
        int numCount;


        //retrieveing length of ToysMade array dimensions if less than 0 repeat untill last dimension filled
        for (int i = 0; i < ToysMade.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < ToysMade.GetLength(1); ii++)
            {
                //taking user input for array dimension 0 "first dimension" then increment it by 1 after input ready for next dimension "i + 1"
                value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Value For " + days[ii] + " of week " + (i + 1).ToString() + " Enter Value");

                try
                {
                    //making sure for only int past through 
                    while (!(int.TryParse(value, out numCount)))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Not a valid number, please try again.");
                        value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Value for " + days[i] + " of week " + (i + 1).ToString() + " Enter Value");
                    }
                    // taking values enterd from user and set next dimension for next input by incrementing it
                    ToysMade[i, ii] = numCount;

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Value enterd is not in a valid format");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this wont fix your problem but with nested loops is pretty normal to use i and j for indices. as for summing, Just use use a nested loop and read like you wrote them while adding the value in each element to a sum variable.

Comment: Ok cool ill try give it ago thanks Jacobr365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest put either simple *foreach* loop

```
  int total = 0;

  foreach (var item in ToysMade)
    total += item;
```

or nested loops which are typical for 2d arrays

```
  int total = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < ToysMade.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < ToysMade.GetLength(1); j++) 
      total += ToysMade[i, j];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq by creating an `IEnumerable<int>`from `ToysMade`;

```
var total = ToysMade.Cast<int>().Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys awesome works thanks heaps again

```
   public void Sum()
    {
        int total = 0;

        for(int i = 0;i < ToysMade.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < ToysMade.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                total += ToysMade[i, j];
            }
        }
        txtOutput.Text += "\r\nThe sum of products is: " + total.ToString();
    }
```